# Signature mismatch with types in modules/functors

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

Excuse my potential misuse of terminology, I'm still not very comfortable with OCaml.

We have a functor with the following (abridged) signature:

```
  module type FUNCTORA = sig
    type input
    type output
    type key
    type inter

    val my_function : input list -> (key * output) list Deferred.t

  end
```

Next, we implement it as such.  MYAPP has the same types as above.

```
  module MyFunctor (App : MyAPP) : FUNCTORA = struct
    type input = App.input
    type output = App.output
    type key = App.key
    type inter App.value

    let my_function lst = ... 
  end
```

When trying to compile the implementation, we get this error:

```
   Error: Signature mismatch:
   ...
   Values do not match:
     val my_function :
       App.input list ->
       (App.key * App.output) list Async_kernel.Deferred.t
   is not included in
     val my_function :
       input list -> (key * output) list Async.Std.Deferred.t
```

It doesn't consider input to include App.input etc, even though we set them to be the same type.  How can we get this to type check?

Answer (score 0):

If I make the following changes:

```
MyAPP => FUNCTORA (* Since you say they are the same *)

type inter App.value  =>  type inter = App.inter (* Syntax/name error *)

Deferred.t => option (* To limit dependence on other modules *)
```

Then your code compiles for me.

Possibly the problem is with `Deferred.t`. There are two distinct looking types in the error message.